# No route matches [GET] for route with constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, regex-lookarounds

Have been No route error for a route with constraints. Please find below my route code and the string I want to match it with.

**Route:**

```
get '/product/:product_title', to: 'frontend_pages#product' , 
    constraints: { product_title: /[A-Za-z0-9-]/ }
```

**Matching String:** www.mylink.com/product/this-is-the-matching-string

Would really appreciate any help that will come my way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let look around constraints part in your defining route. Issue is at here

```
constraints: { product_title: /[A-Za-z0-9-]/ }
```

regular expression that you write is fail
Try yourself with:

```
product_title: /[A-Za-z0-9]+/
```

Hope this will help you.